# Unable to connect wordpress CRM plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this plugin called "Cart2CRM" it used to work fine until a couple of days. 
Now im getting this error:

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to crm.website.nl:80
>   (Connection refused) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/Cart2CRM/inc/admin/nusoap.php
>   on line 2330

Line 2330:

```
$this->debug('calling fsockopen with host ' . $host . ' connection_timeout ' . $connection_timeout);
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        // open socket
        if($connection_timeout > 0){
            $this->fp = fsockopen( $host, $this->port, $this->errno, $this->error_str, $connection_timeout);
        } else {
2330 -->            $this->fp = fsockopen( $host, $this->port, $this->errno, $this->error_str);
        }
```

Comment: is crm.website.nl an actual hostname you're trying to connect?

Comment: Yes it is, its basically a website that syncs with woocommerce. The purpose is to see all placed orders on a website without having to login to wordpress. @sotona

Comment: well, I tried to look for this domain: 
# host crm.website.nl
Host crm.website.nl not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: oh, the name is not actually crm.website.nl.. It's a name i used for privacy reasons.

Comment: so I'd suggest to try to connect to this hostname with curl and if it works, then you apparently should dig into your logs, or check http daemon/firewall settings if not

Comment: @sotona something like curl -v crm.website.nl ?

Comment: I'd rather say  "curl -i -X GET http://crm.website.nl"

Comment: It gave me a response @sotona